# iterate in all Dataframe rows and perform startswith()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my df look like this:

[image: df]

as you can see the User starts with 'ff' and it could be in access column or any other column rather than user column.

i want to create a new column in this df called "UserID" where whenever the is 'ff' in all the columns copy this value to my new column "UserId"

i have been using this method which is working fine but i have to repeat this line in all the columns:

```
hist.loc[hist.User.str.startswith("ff",na=False),'UserId']=hist['User'].str[2:]
```

is there any other method i can use to loop over all rows at once?

thanks

Comment: Do you mean if all columns start with 'ff' copy the rest of the string from USER column and None if not so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NumPy + Pandas solution below.

In case of ambiguity (several `ff`-strings in a row) leftmost occurance is taken. In case of absence (no `ff`-string in a row) `NaN` value is used.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64630650#main.py)

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'user':    ['fftest',     'fwadmin',     'fshelpdesk3', 'no',   'ffone'],
    'access':  ['fwadmin',    'ffuser2',     'fwadmin',     'user', 'fftwo'],
    'station': ['fshelpdesk', 'fshelpdesk2', 'ffuser3',     'here', 'three'],
})

sv = df.values.astype(np.str)
ix = np.argwhere(np.char.startswith(sv, 'ff'))[::-1].T
df.loc[ix[0], 'UserID'] = pd.Series(sv[(ix[0], ix[1])]).str[2:].values

print(df)
```

Output:

```
          user   access      station UserID
0       fftest  fwadmin   fshelpdesk   test
1      fwadmin  ffuser2  fshelpdesk2  user2
2  fshelpdesk3  fwadmin      ffuser3  user3
3           no     user         here    NaN
4        ffone    fftwo        three    one
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are cool with picking only the first occurence:

```
df['UserID'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x.str.startswith('ff')][:1], axis=1)
```

Comment: ```x[x.str.startswith('ff')][0]``` will give index error if no column starts with 'ff'

Comment: please post the complete answer

Answer (score 0):

Hey here is my attempt at solving the problem, hope it helps.

```
d = df[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.startswith('ff'))]
df['user_id'] = d['user'].fillna(d['access'].fillna(d['station']))
```

**Result**

```
        user   access      station  user_id
0       fftest  fwadmin   fshelpdesk   fftest
1      fwadmin  ffuser2  fshelpdesk2  ffuser2
2  fshelpdesk3  fwadmin      ffuser3  ffuser3
```